# one hot encoding of a binary feature when using XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, data-analysis

I am well aware that when using categorical features with tree based models such as random forest and gradient boosting there is no need to drop one level from N-level categorical features. For example, the following color feature with three levels can be made three binary features.

```
Color|| Color_R | Color_B | Color_G
____ ||_________|_________|________
 R   ||   1     |   0     |   0
 B   ||   0     |   1     |   0
 G   ||   0     |   0     |   1
```

However, what about binary feature (E.g., TRUE/FALSE, MALE/FEMALE)? Should it be kept as a single binary feature (Option I below) or should it also be one-hot encoded into two binary features (Option II below)

**Option I**

```
Gender || Gender  | 
____   ||_________|
M      ||   1     | 
F      ||   0     | 
M      ||   1     |
```

**Option II**

```
Gender || Gender_M | Gender_F 
____   || _________|_________
M      ||    1     |   0     
F      ||    0     |   1     
M      ||    1     |   0
```

Comment: Reposted and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/438875/232706